# Adding a value to a cell in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that will increase a cell value by 1.
The goal is to make the value of AM39 increase by 1, but not go past 2.
I have fixed all syntax errors, however I've tried running the script but the script hasn't done anything.

What is wrong is this function?

```
function incrementCellValuesByOne() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("AM39");
var cell, cellValue;

if (cellValue == cell.getValue()) {
    cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);

    if (cellValue >= 2) {
        cellValue = 2;
    }
}
}
```

edit:

```
range.setValue(value + 1);

if (cellValue >= 2) {
    cellValue = 2;
}
```

Comment: cellValue is not initialized anywhere in the code posted…!

Comment: cellValue where is the cellValue initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some wrong in define and ordering of statements! Try this:

```
function incrementCellValuesByOne() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var cell, cellValue;
    cellValue = "Something you should make here!";
    cell = sheet.getRange("AM39");

    if (cellValue == cell.getValue()) {
        cell.setValue(cellValue + 1);
        if (cellValue >= 2) {
            cellValue = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the problem, however I can't get these two to work together. Do you happen to know how?

    range.setValue(value + 1);
    
    if (cellValue >= 2) {
        cellValue = 2;
    }